# Regular expression that returns numbers following a specific letter until the next letter

Tags: r, regex, string, substring

I need a regular expression that returns a specific letter and the following (one or two) digits until the next letter.
For example, I would like to extract how many carbons (C) are in a formula using regular expressions in R

```
strings <- c("C16H4ClNO2", "CH8O", "F2Ni")
```

I need an expression that returns the number of C which can be one or 2 digits and that does not return the number after chlorine (Cl).

```
substr(strings,regexpr("C[0-9]+",strings) + 1, regexpr("[ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]+",strings) -1)
[1] "16" "C"  ""
```

but the answer I want to be returned is

```
"16","1","0"
```

Moreover, I would like the regular expression to automatically locate the next letter and stop before it, instead of having a final position which I specify as a letter not being a C.

Comment: is regex requirement? there are much simpler solutions, but their applicability depends on your real problem. simplest open that text in notepad++, open search window type C and click count - you can set more rules there or even use regex there if really needed; for software type application I would use python, read all text in var and look for something in var

Comment: sorry - maybe misunderstood question

Comment: you can check regex101.com and test there, but just as advice instead of whole alphabet you could use [A-Z]or [a-zA-Z] if small letters included also digit is \d so C\d+ will find you all you need

Comment: You can do `sub("C(\\d+).*", "\\1", sub("C([^0-9]+)", "C1\\1", ifelse(!grepl("C", strings), paste0("C0", strings), strings)))
#[1] "16" "1"  "0"`

Comment: thanks, drako. I'm not using the whole alphabet: Here, I don't want to use C for instance - how can I exclude C? I would like to use a regular expression in R. my real dataset are two merged dataframes with chemical compounds for each of which i want to count the certain elements from their formula.

Answer (score 9):

`makeup` in the CHNOSZ package will parse a chemical formula. Here are some alternatives that use it:

**1)** Create a list `L` of such fully parsed formulas and then for each one check if it has a `"C"` component and return its value or 0 if none:

```
library(CHNOSZ)

L <- Map(makeup, strings)
sapply(L, function(x) if ("C" %in% names(x)) x[["C"]] else 0)
## C16H4ClNO2       CH8O       F2Ni 
##         16          1          0
```

Note that `L` is a list of the fully parsed formulas in case you have other requirements:

```
> L
$C16H4ClNO2
 C  H Cl  N  O 
16  4  1  1  2 

$CH8O
C H O 
1 8 1 

$F2Ni
 F Ni 
 2  1
```

**1a)**  By adding `c(C = 0)` to each list component we can avoid having to test for the existence of carbon yielding the following shorter version of the `sapply` line in (1):

```
sapply(lapply(L, c, c(C = 0)), "[[", "C")
```

**2)** This one-line variation of (1) gives the same answer as in (1) except for names.  It appends `"C0"` to each formula to avoid having to test for the existence of carbon:

```
sapply(lapply(paste0(strings, "C0"), makeup), "[[", "C")
## [1] 16  1  0
```

**2a)** Here is a variation of (2) that eliminates the `lapply` by using the fact that `makeup` will accept a matrix:

```
sapply(makeup(as.matrix(paste0(strings, "C0"))), "[[", "C")
## [1] 16  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for two things:

- C + a number immediately afterwards => **match** this number
- C followed by another UPPERCASE letter (another chemical element, that is) => **count** C

If you're able to install another library, you might get along with:

```
library("stringr")
strings <- c("C16H4ClNO2", "CH8O", "F2Ni")

str1 <- str_extract(strings, '(?<=C)\\d+')
str2 <- str_count(strings, 'C[A-Z]') 
str2[!is.na(str1)] = str1[!is.na(str1)]
str2
# [1] "16" "1"  "0"
```

This does a lot of fancy things, `str1` looks for the first condition (C followed by another digits), while `str2` looks for the second condition. The last line combines the two vectors

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `base R`

```
sub("C(\\d+).*", "\\1", sub("C([^0-9]+)", 
  "C1\\1", ifelse(!grepl("C", strings), paste0("C0", strings), strings)))
#[1] "16" "1"  "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ifelse(str_extract(strings,'(?<=C)(\\d+|)')=='',1,str_extract(strings,'(?<=C)(\\d+|)'))
[1] "16" "1"  NA
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. You can do quite a bit to improve your answer by explaining how it works or why it's better to alternatives.